# how to download database records as Execl files in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, digital-ocean, laravel-5.6, maatwebsite-excel, lemp

iv been using maatwebsite/excel to download database records as excel files.this workes on my local machine but when i upload it to digital ocean VPS it doesnt download "give a whoops page". after doing some research i ran into a post that mentioned it might not be supported for long.

so can anyone please help with eighter a better solution to download excel files OR suggestions on how i can resolve my problem

I am using a LEMP stack incase this is relevant.

BY the way i am still new to all this :{ hence the possibly novice question

Comment: set `APP_DEBUG=true`  in `.env` file and You'll see that reason of `whoops`

Comment: thanks for th tip ...for some reason i ddnt think to do that

Comment: ok,You can disable debug, but You can check storage folder for app logs for crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason my "maatwebsite/excel" was not installed on my vps .so i had to use composer to install it and its dependencies

-> composer require maatwebsite/excel
->composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet

in my case thats what i needed. i also had to restart the server afterwards

also concider this

. download('xlsx') xlsx package was not installed so changed it to xls